# How do I send specific data based on which cell is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with a bunch of concerts, and when x cell is clicked, I want the artist of that concert to populate the new tableView. Below is the code for the first view controller (the view controller with all the concerts).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
var arrayOfConcerts: [concert] = [concert]()


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpConcerts()
    self.tableView1.rowHeight = 145.0
}

func setUpConcerts()
  {
    var ACL = concert(imageName: "ACL2015.png")
    let Landmark = concert(imageName: "Landmark.png")
    let BostonCalling = concert(imageName: "BostonCalling.png")
    let Lolla = concert(imageName: "Lolla.png")
    arrayOfConcerts.append(ACL)
    arrayOfConcerts.append(Landmark)
    arrayOfConcerts.append(BostonCalling)
    arrayOfConcerts.append(Lolla)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfConcerts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = self.tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let concerts = arrayOfConcerts[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(concerts.imageName)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("concertartist", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{

}

}
```

> Below is the code for the Artist View Controller (the second
>   viewcontroller). This tableView should be populated with specific
>   artists.

How would I go about doing that?

```
class ArtistConcerts: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var arrayOfArtists: [artist] = [artist]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewArtists: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setUpArtists()
}

func setUpArtists()
{

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfArtists.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableViewArtists.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let artists = arrayOfArtists[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(artists.imageNameArtist)
    return cell
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the prepareForSegue method.

```
 let vc  = segue!.destinationViewController as! ArtistConcerts

 if let rowSelected = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
     vc.arrayOfArtists = artistsPerforming[0]//this is an array
 }
```

then, set whatever data you need to actually populate the tableView in that new view controller. I am not 100% sure on what you are trying to do though. Does my answer make sense?

Comment: Sort of, just to clarify I'll provide and example. There are 4 concerts, so on the first tableview 4 cells will be filled with concert a,b,c,d. Different artists will be performing at concert a,b,c,d. Artist x,y,z will be performing at concert a. Artist a,b,c will be performing at concert b. etc. When cell a is clicked artist x,y,z will appear, when cell b is clicked artist a,b,c will appear.

Comment: So, I updated my answer a little bit. So, say the user pressed concert a, then you would pass an array of artists [a,b,c] into the vc.arrayOfArtists, that would then be used to populate your UITableView in ArtistsConcerts.

Answer (score 0):

you can send data once the cell is pressed to another viewcontroller by using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `prepareForSegue` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath + prepareForSegue`

let's say you are using prepareForSegue, things you will need

> the segue identifier name
>
> cast the destinationController to the controller you want to send the data
>
> the indexPath.row where the cell was selected
>
> then set the variable or variables or data structure  that should receive data

**Create a segue when you pressed CTRL + Drag from your cell into another viewcontroller**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
     if segue.identifier == "Name_Of_Segue"
    {
   
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! NAME_Of_ViewController
        let indexPath =  mytableview.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let data = arrayOfArtists[indexPath.row]
       
        destination.artist = data
    }
```

`mytableview` is an IBOutlet from your tableview

`artist` is a variable that is declared in your destination controller

`destination.artist = data` this line of code is passing data from the specific cell then send it to your destination cell